# Getting better error messages from Play JSON API

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Examples of the kind of error messages produced by Play JSON API:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> Json.obj("k" -> Json.obj("m" -> 7))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"k":{"m":7}}

scala> (res0 \ "p").as[String]
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:69)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:10)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.as(JsValue.scala:65)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsUndefined.as(JsValue.scala:98)
    at .<init>(<console>:12)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    // gazillion lines more

scala> (res0 \ "k" \ "m").as[String]
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:69)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:10)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.as(JsValue.scala:65)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsNumber.as(JsValue.scala:108)
    at .<init>(<console>:12)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    // gazillion lines more
```

Is there a way to get better error messages out of this API? For example, the error messages for above two cases could look like `No value found at JsPath \ "p"`, `Value found at JsPath \ "k" \ "m" cannot be read as type String` etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes using `JsValue.as[T]` isn't robust in this case:

`res0 \ "p"` returns `JsUndefined` which is then applied to an implicit `Reads[String]` and it says "hey that's not a String"... That's true but not what you expect ;)

the better way IMHO uses `Reads` on `JsPath` directly:

```
scala> ((__ \ "p").read[String]).reads(res0)
res7: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[String] = JsError(List((/p,List(ValidationError(validate.error.missing-path,WrappedArray())))))

scala> ((__ \ "k" \ "m").read[String]).reads(res0)
res8: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[String] = JsError(List((/k/m,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsstring,WrappedArray())))))
```

Here you have a better message about missing-path.
It even notifies the missing path in first param in JsError.

Concerning messages as nice strings, you can use a local message to map the key.
BTW, those Json errors message are not quite standardized with respect to other error messages in Play such as Forms. I think we will improve it in a future release of Play.

Finally, when you want to send Json validation errors to the client, there is a helper function in `JsError` to use with `JsResult.recoverTotal`

```
scala> ((__ \ "k" \ "m").read[String]).reads(res0).recoverTotal( e => JsError.toFlatJson(e) )
res11: java.io.Serializable = {"obj.k.m":[{"msg":"validate.error.expected.jsstring","args":[]}]}
```

This is just a raw version of this kind of function. If you need an another format, I advise to look at toFlatJson implementation and write your own.

Have fun ;)

Comment: Why is not the default way how the default accessor methods on `JsValue` work? Error reporting matters. :(

Comment: @mandubian - I have Long type in one of the property of scala case class. but when i convert json to seq of that class it gives me "erro.expected.long"

Comment: If it even told at which line the error occurs it would not be *that* terrible.