# Getting exception line number in Play 2.1 Json Api?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1

The stacktrace of JSON api errors doesn't show the line number of my code. It's time consuming to search in all my files for the possible reasons...

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16747031/930450) - that is useful, but this is thread is only about the line numbers.

The stacktrace looks like:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:143) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:139) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]

play.api.libs.json.JsResultException:     JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(validate.error.expected.jsarray,WrappedArray())))))
at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$$anonfun$2.apply(JsValue.scala:67) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:69) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:10) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.as(JsValue.scala:65) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
at play.api.libs.json.JsNumber.as(JsValue.scala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have an elegant solution for this, but the detailed stacktrace can be found in `logs\application.log` - it helps me in such cases

Comment: Ahh... you're right! there I see the line number (I'm new to Play and still missing some basic stuff) thanks.